# How can I show different paragraphs with one function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a paragraph if I click on the title.
The issue I'm having is that I have multiple titles with each a different paragraph but only one function to handle it.
Is this even possible?
The function only shows the paragraph for the first title.

I have tried with:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".class1, .class2")
```

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2")
```

Both don't seem to work.

```js
function unhide() {
    var hid = document.querySelectorAll(".lefthanded", ".measurements");
    // Emulates jQuery $(element).is(':hidden');
    if(hid[0].offsetWidth > 0 && hid[0].offsetHeight > 0) {
        hid[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

```
            <a onclick="unhide()"><h3>Preinstalled Left Hand Kit</h3></a>
            <div class="lefthanded">
                <p>This is the paragraph</p>
            </div>

            <a onclick="unhide()"><h3>Product Measurements Requests</h3></a>
            <div class="measurements">
                <p>This is a different paragraph</p>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns multiple elements but you're only checking the first by using `[0]`? Please create a [mre].

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (including HTML) so that we can replicate what you are trying to do.

Comment: "don't seem to work" is incredibly vague; please clarify.

Comment: Loop through all the elements of `hid` instead of just `[0]`.

Comment: `hid.forEach(paragraph => ...)`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".lefthanded", ".measurements");` qSA takes only a single argument, `".measurements"` is ignored. And if an element has a width and a height, it's not `:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick easy and efficient ways to tackle this is use `<detail>` tag like this:

```
<details>
  <summary>Your Title</summary>
  <p>This is your paragraph</p>
</details>
```

[More about the tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#lefthanded").click(function(){
    $(".lefthanded").show();
  }); 
  $("#measurements").click(function(){
    $(".measurements").show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


            <a id="lefthanded"><h3>Preinstalled Left Hand Kit</h3></a>
            <div style="display: none;" class="lefthanded">
                <p>This is the paragraph</p>
            </div>

            <a id="measurements"><h3>Product Measurements Requests</h3></a>
            <div style="display: none;" class="measurements">
                <p>This is a different paragraph</p>
            </div>
```

The easy way to do this is (With Jquery):
Just target the paragraph
Hide it with `.hide()` method.
The show it on click with the selector
`($selector).click(()=>{$(paragraph#id).show()})`
In this way you can easily do the work.